# C Strings Library

Tags: c, string, unicode, char

Is there a C strings library for C (not C++) that implements an abstraction over `char *` and `wchar_t *` strings?

The requirements are:

1. to be BSD/MIT/CDDL licenced
2. implements some kind of reference count mechanism
3. has support for regular expressions
4. has Unicode support

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using Plan9 libraries. For Unix there's [plan9port](http://swtch.com/plan9port/) or the more lightweight [9base](http://tools.suckless.org/9base). For windows I use a custom the port that come with [Go](http://golang.org/).

Answer (score 2):

What about [this](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/)? Looks good, at least matches some of your criteria, but I didn't use it so it must be checked. At least I see BSD license here so it could be useful point to start.

Answer (score 2):

Glib can do most of that, but is LGPL: http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/

I don't think you can find refcounting in any string library in C though... It's just not that easy to do. You can make a thin wrapper around `gchar*` yourself if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) might be what you need. It's licensed under [Open Source License](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/license.html), and doesn't exactly abstract char*/wchar_t* (see: http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/unicode_wchar_t.html), but it might be what you need.